# It's possible use travis ci only has a build tool?es

Tags: maven, travis-ci

I have a maven project and I'd like use travis ci only has a build tool and skip maven tests.
To compile the project I use the following maven command:
`mvn clean package eclipse:eclipse -D eclipse.pde install` and I put this under `install:` flag. Now I want skip the test how can I do that?

Comment: Please reword your question, it's hard to understand.

Comment: @thSoft I only want compile the project using travis ci and skip the test. At the moment after installing the project travis ci runs mvn test but I don't want run it

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the following in your .travis.yml:

`script: /bin/true`

Do note though, that failures in the install section are treated differently than errors in the script section. If the above is your build command, then I'd recommend putting this command in the script section and put `/bin/true` in the install section.